# generalization of LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, lu-decomposition

I've just begun studying numerical approaches to LU decomposition and it got me thinking. Is there a more "general" (not sure if this is the right term for what I'm describing) form of LU decomposition? Meaning, do algorithms exist to solve A = L*X where L is a given nonsingular lower triangular matrix, and X is an unknown matrix. A would be the n-by-n matrix we are trying to factor here. I'm almost 100% sure it would be slower than LU. If someone could elaborate on this problem or point me to resources studying this that would be incredible, thank you!

Comment: Suppose you are given $L$ and also know $A$, and wouldn't that just be $X = L^{-1} A$? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: True, but computing inverses is quite expensive numerically (in both the dense and especially in the sparse case) right? So it should be avoided if we're looking for efficiency? I was thinking of numerically feasible algorithms.

Comment: Ah ok. In this case we can leverage the property that $L$ is lower-triangular to perform back-substitution efficiently. Let $a_i$ be the $i$th column of $A$ and $x_i$ the $i$th column of $X$. Then we may solve each $a_i = L x_i$ in parallel via back-substitution.

Comment: That makes sense thank you! I was wondering if there are any faster algorithms for this problem as well. Does this sort of problem have a name? Having a hard time finding the literature from simply googling.

Comment: In general, what kind of matrix factorizations you can do depends on the assumptions on $A$. If $A$ happens to be positive semidefinite, a Cholesky factorization is even faster: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition.

Comment: More generally, singular value decomposition is applicable to any matrix. It is often useful, but not necessarily the fastest.

Comment: There are other matrix factorizations. PLU, P a permutation matrix, with some pivoting scheme. The QR decomposition, where $Q$ might be encoded as a sequence of Householder reflectors or Givens rotations. Then in the sparse context there is the ILU, the incomplete LU decomposition, where the aim is to preserve the sparsity pattern and increase the diagonal dominance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, one such algorithm is simply Gaussian elimination... When you row reduce a non-singular matrix to an upper triangular form, the final result is the matrix $U$ ( or at least one possible matrix $U$) in the $LU$ decomposition. The $L$ matrix can also be recovered from the elementary transformation matrices used to perform row reduction.